# SwiftUI List row padding changes based on dynamic content

Tags: swiftui

I have a `List` with `ListRows` that have some dynamic content. I have a "top row" with a button to expand and show a "bottom row" - something like this:

```
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            HStack {
                Text("Test")
                    .font(.headline)
                    .background(Color.green)
                Spacer()
                Button(action: {self.showBody.toggle()},
                       label: {Image(systemName: "icloud.and.arrow.down")})
            }
                .background(Color.yellow)

            if showBody {
                Text("<insert body>")
                    .font(Constants.Fonts.NotesRow.preview)
                    .background(Color.blue)
            }
        }
```

Here is what it looks like. I set `.listRowInsets` to 0, but notice that there is padding on the top and bottom (that's the black lines above and below the colored lines).

[image]

When I click "expand", the padding changes and it gives a pretty jarring experience:

[image]

Is there a way to fix this so that the row expands?

*Update*

It appears that if I set `.padding()` on the row, I get the right behavior. If I try to adjust the padding smaller, it has the undesirable behavior of "shrinking the padding space".

Here is an example of it working as expected with `.padding()` - notice the gray spaces are the same around the row content and have completely taken over the row (ie, there's no black):

[image]
[image]

If I change the padding to `.padding(5)`, you can see that the row doesn't take up the full row, and the black from the row appears. When expanding, it consumes up the black, making the experience undesired:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution might be as follow (paddings, etc. are of course configurable, just a direction to show that content can fill row completely if needed)

[image: demo]

```
struct ListRow: View {
    @State private var showBody = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            HStack {
                Text("Test")
                    .font(.headline)
                    .background(Color.green)
                Spacer()
                Button(action: {self.showBody.toggle()},
                       label: {Image(systemName: "icloud.and.arrow.down")})
            }
            .background(Color.yellow)

            if showBody {
                Text("<insert body>")
                    .font(.subheadline)
                    .background(Color.blue)
            }
            Spacer()
        }
        .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())
        .listRowBackground(Color.yellow)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach (0 ..< 2) { _ in
                ListRow()
            }
        }
        .environment(\.defaultMinListRowHeight, 20)
    }
}
```

Comment: That's not quite what I'm asking. If you look at the second screen shot, the row has "lost its padding". That makes the experience jarring, because the green label "moves up" to fill the top padding to make space. I'd rather the gray "expand the bottom" and the black padding seen on the first image stays on the second image. IE - it should be "expand down" and not "expand center and remove padding".

Comment: yeah that was it - I had to set the height to a small amount so that the row took up all the padding. Thanks!